# expo-contacts doesn't filtering the contacts with fields option in react native Expo 37

Tags: react-native, expo, contacts

I'm developing the mobile app using react native expo.

The Expo SDK version is 37.0.0

For filtering and showing my contacts, I used the "expo-contacts" package.
But I can't filter my contacts with "Fields" options.

my code part:

```
useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.PHONE_NUMBERS]
        });
        if(data.length > 0)
          console.log(data);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

But I can't get filtering contact, I got all my contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code as below : Note Contacts.PHONE_NUMBERS is not valid

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status === 'granted') {
            const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
                fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
            });

            if (data.length > 0) {
                console.log(data);//do some action here
            }
        }
    })();
}, []);
```